# 3 errors when trying to convert image to base64

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I've referenced other materials, but none of them seems to work with my images. I'm trying to get the dataURL output.

The three errors I receive are:

> [Error] Origin https://www.majoroutput.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>
> [Error] Cannot load image
> https://majoroutput.com/eJxlz9ENgCAMRdFdGEXD12u6zdvfllIpUGOIxyvBpmO4jQFiWS-ddBszzDJaX4g/Um9fo-beL6fbcYzuuTtW7Quxm3tVzZcej425dLoIgTlkIdKw_D-8EhTDI7vUpmM/Sb_DqrxEmRTVwWKNI-6pqcvA==@1.png
> due to access control checks.
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://www.majoroutput.com is
> not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> (Sb_DqrxEmRTVwWKNI-6pqcvA==@1.png, line 0)

```
function getDataUrl(img) {
   const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = img.width;
   canvas.height = img.height;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}

var originalImg = new Image;
originalImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
originalImg.src = "https://majoroutput.com/eJxlz9ENgCAMRdFdGEXD12u6zdvfllIpUGOIxyvBpmO4jQFiWS-ddBszzDJaX4g/Um9fo-beL6fbcYzuuTtW7Quxm3tVzZcej425dLoIgTlkIdKw_D-8EhTDI7vUpmM/Sb_DqrxEmRTVwWKNI-6pqcvA==@1.png";

originalImg.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
   const dataUrl = getDataUrl(event.currentTarget);
   console.log(dataUrl);
});
```

Comment: The error here is that their server won't allow your browser to access one of their resources unless the request came from their web site.  You need to read about CORS.

Comment: It's my own website and the script is also running on my own website.

Comment: So what is the reason it doesn't work then??

Comment: `originaImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"` -- why do you have that?

Comment: Whether I include it or not, I have the same problem. I've even wrote anonymous with a lower case A.

Comment: Dunno.  I can load your image from MY browser.  Have you configured any CORS stuff in your Apache setup?